# What is best tool for Android Mobile Automation Test

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, automated-tests, integration-testing, testng

I want to automate test of my Android Application. I am wondering which will be the best tool which is may be recommended by Google for  Android Mobile Application Automation Testing. Can any suggest me ?

Also I want to use with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read Google's recommendations here:

- https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/testing.html